# Как вставить в input шрифтовую иконку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите как и можно ли вставить в input шрифтовую иконку. Например, FontAwesome. 
Чтобы просто вставить картинку, это можно сделать через **background-image**, а как вставить шрифтовую иконку не могу догадаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.wrapper input[type="text"] {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper input[type="text"]:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -5px;
    content: "\f007";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

что бы вставить иконку с данного ресурса нужно сначала выбрать иконку на сайте =>потом нажать на нее=>высветиться снизу код по типу  и потом просто вставить его в HTML код где вы хотите чтобы он стоял.ссылка на сайт вот http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 0):

Оберните иконку и `input` блоком, к примеру блоком `div` или `label`.
Задайте блоку `position relative`, соответственно детям `absolute` и выровняйте относительно друг друга как вам нужно.