# Как добавить крестик вовнутрь input для сброса

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

Как можно реализовать сброс введенных данных внутри самого `input`? Скажем, добавить крестик справа, при нажатии на который происходит сброс введенных значений. Я могу сделать кнопку рядом для сброса, но не знаю как поместить крестик вовнутрь. Мне не нужно добавлять иконку, нужна лишь стандартная отмена

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить иконку в input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712295/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-input)

Comment: Внизу есть более простой способ для добавления сброса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить в input шрифтовую иконку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517950/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-input-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: да вы че прикалываетесь что ли? Какой дубликат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `input type="search"`

```html
<input type="search">
```

Ну и если вам нужно через js то вот

```css
x-field{
display:inline;
position:relative;
}
x-field .close {
position:absolute;
padding:0 5px;
right:0;
}
```

```html
<x-field>
<input type="text" id = "text">
<span class="close" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.value = ''">
&times;
</span>
</x-field>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPQkc.png

Comment: не знаю что у вас, http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-search

Comment: "1 - Does not use a special search-specific UI for the field" - вот это вот у меня)

Comment: кажется да, надо стилизовать

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать задать родителю `position` отличный от `static`, например,
`position:relative`, а кнопке `position:absolute` и с помощью `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` разместить её, где нужно.

Вот посмотри [здесь](https://fiddle.jshell.net/z2rfhLLc/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.offsetX < 51) {
    input.value = '';
  }
})

input.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.offsetX < 51) {
    input.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }else{
  input.style.cursor = 'text';
  }
})
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.fontstorage.com/import/adventpro.css";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #065b79;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(http://nouveal.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable-nouveal/img/croix@2x.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Advent';
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: .1px solid #fff;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="FiFa">
```